# jQuery Load - Wait Option

Tags: jquery

I have a simple div that is for loading multiple forms, however when switching forms the previous still shows before the new form is loaded, how do I ensure the form is loaded before the dialog shows?

```
function editAppointment(event) {
    $("#appPlaceholder").load("/Schedule/Edit/" + event.id+");
   //Dialog window
    $('#appointmentModal').show();
}

function newAppointment(event) {
    $("#appPlaceholder").load("/Schedule/New/");            
    //Dialog window
    $('#appointmentModal').show();
}
```

Comment: your code is still flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load() can take a callback as a second argument, which is fired after load() has finished.

```
$("#appPlaceholder").load(
    "/Schedule/Edit/" + event.id,
    function () {
         $('#appointmentModal').show();
    }
);
```